# Recommendation Add-On in Orange

Tags: recommendation-engine, orange

I want to explore the use of the recommendation add-on in my class later this semester.  The Add-On does not appear in the list that comes with the interface, but when I click add-more in the upper right, and type Recommendation, a list appears in the box along with an associated version number, currently `0.3.1`.

I select to install, Orange tells me to restart the program, and when I do, the widgets and section Recommendation are not visible in the UI, and the Add-on is not visible within the Add-on sections as well.  If I type Recommendation to "Add more" again, I see it checked and it suggests that it is installed.

Is there a setting that needs to be adjusted for this toolset to appear via the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around, thankfully due to the Related questions, there was a similar issue with the Bioinformatics.

To install the package above, instead of typing Recommendation, we need to use `orange3-recommendation`.

That did the trick.